# Calculate percentage of a values occurence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using this dataframe:

```
Car make | Driver's Gender
Ford     | m
GMC      | m
GMC      | f
Ferrari  | f
```

I would like to calculate the percentage of each make's male drivers.

```
Car make  | Male drivers
Ford      | 100
GMC       | 50
Ferrari   | 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Compare second column for `m` and then aggregate `mean`:

```
df1 = (df["Driver's Gender"].eq('m')
       .groupby(df['Car make'], sort=False)
       .mean()
       .mul(100)
      .reset_index(name='Male drivers'))
print (df1)
  Car make  Male drivers
0     Ford         100.0
1      GMC          50.0
2  Ferrari           0.0
```

Another idea with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and `normalize` parameter:

```
df2 = pd.crosstab(df['Car make'], df["Driver's Gender"], normalize=0).mul(100)
print (df2)
Driver's Gender      f      m
Car make                     
Ferrari          100.0    0.0
Ford               0.0  100.0
GMC               50.0   50.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few approaches:

Quick and dirty by converting "m" to 100 and "f" to 0and taking a mean

```
df["Male drivers"] = df["Driver's gender"].apply(lambda x: 100 if x=="m" else 0)
male_freq = df.groupby("Car make").mean(numeric_only=True)
```

Using groupby and a manual frequency calculation

```
male_freq = df.groupby("Car make").agg(lambda x: 100*sum(x == "m") / len(x))
```

Using groupby and value_counts

```
def get_male_frequency(series):
    val_counts = series.value_counts(normalize=True)
    return 100 * val_counts.get("m", 0)

male_freq = df.groupby("Car make").agg(get_male_frequency)
```

Or a more general version of the same:

```
def get_frequency(value_of_interest):
    def _get_frequency(series):
        val_counts = series.value_counts(normalize=True)
        return 100 * val_counts.get(value_of_interest, 0)
return _get_frequency

x = df.groupby("Car make").agg(get_frequency("m"))
```

They all output the following:

> ```
>           Driver's gender
> Car make                 
> Ferrari               0.0
> Ford                100.0
> GMC                  50.0
> ```